# R to latex - Coloring numbers automatically

Tags: r, colors, latex, xtable

I have a (long) R matrix. eg:

```
matrix <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.01), ncol=4)
```

I would like to find a way to colour, for instance, the 15% more important numbers of each column, **BEFORE** doing the latex extraction as follow:

```
print(xtable(matrix, align = c("r","r","r","r","r")),
type = "latex",
floating = FALSE,
tabular.environment = "longtable")
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to adapt this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895829/how-can-xtable-do-cell-coloring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a dirty solution

```
matrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(200, rate=.01), ncol=4))
```

Set the loop

```
for(i in 1:length(matrix[1,])) {
quant  <- quantile(matrix[,i], prob = 0.85, na.rm = TRUE)   
   for(j in 1:length(matrix[,1])) {         
       if(as.numeric(matrix[j,i]) > quant) {
       matrix[j,i] <- paste("\\cellcolor{red!25}", matrix[j,i], sep="", collapse = NULL)} 
       else {}  
} } # close both loops
```

Then print the result in latex

```
print(xtable(matrix), 
      type = "latex",
      sanitize.text.function = identity)
```

It give an acceptable result. It is important to set: "quant  <- quantile" before the "j" loop. If not the change made during this "j" loop change matrix[,i] into a character vector and it is then impossible to re-compute the quantile.

Don't forget "sanitize.text.function = identity" in the print.