# Making pretty tables in R markdown with latex

Tags: r, data.table, kable

I want to create some 2 colors tables (like in excel, it can be black and white).

I know I can use the kable() function but the table are kinda not good looking. The output I would like to have is a pdf file.

I would also like the header to repeat itself since the tables are on multiple pages.

Anyone got some advices please?

Comment: Check out the `flextable` package

Comment: I'll take a look thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for the ''two colors'' patern you can use the `striped` option from the `kable_styling()` function. About the header repeating itself you will also need to add the `repeat_header` option inside the `kable_styling()` function. You have to install the package `kableExtra` to use those options.

**You can do it this way :**

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(data, "latex", longtable = T, caption = "your_title") %>% 
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header"),
repeat_header_text = "", full_width = F)
```

Does it help you? This will provide you a LaTeX table to knit in R Markdown.

Answer (score -2):

I would not recommend `rmarkdown` but intead `knitr` which uses LaTeX and not markdown. The syntax is very similar and if you know LaTeX is easy to implement. The `xtable` package might also be use for your particular question. Also see this thread: [how can xtable do cell coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895829/how-can-xtable-do-cell-coloring)